# How can i write this filter in my views.py

Tags: python, django, django-models

Hello I have such a question about model filtering, I would like to write a filter that will allow me to display individual tournament groups assigned to a given tournament only in the tab related to that tournament.

this is my models.py

```
class Tournament(models.Model):
    data = models.DateField(null=True)
    tournament_name = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True)
    tournament_creator = models.ForeignKey(Judges, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.tournament_name


class TournamentGroup(models.Model):
    group_name = models.CharField(max_length=256, null=True)
    tournament_name = models.ForeignKey(Tournament, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.group_name


class TournamentUsers(models.Model):
    user_first_name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    user_last_name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    user_tournament = models.ForeignKey(Tournament, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    user_group = models.ForeignKey(TournamentGroup, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user_last_name + ' ' + self.user_first_name
```

and this is my views.py file

```
def content(request, pk):
    tournament = get_object_or_404(Tournament, pk=pk)
    tournament_groups = TournamentGroup.objects.filter(tournament_name=tournament)
    users = TournamentUsers.objects.filter(user_tournament=tournament)
    form = TournamentUsersForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = TournamentUsersForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            form = TournamentUsersForm()

    return render(request, 'ksm_app2/content.html', {'tournament': tournament, 'users': users,
                                                     'form': form, 'tournament_groups': tournament_groups})
```

The user filter works correctly after he has chosen the right tournament but I have a problem with the team, I will appreciate any hint

Comment: Just explain this line more *I have a problem with the team*

Comment: I would like the teams to be equally filtered based on the tournament name and displayed only for the given tournament.

Comment: Isn't it in your code? : `tournament_groups = TournamentGroup.objects.filter(tournament_name=tournament)`

Comment: It's in my code but I'm not sure if it's good because I get error 500 when I create a tournament group

Comment: Now its working but i have problem with displayed users with their groups

Comment: What do you mean by problem? Elaborate or post a traceback